# how to Implement mark/mark all in a bootstrap grid columns?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my Code I need Something like this.[image]

For grid I've used bootstrap grid system like this:

```
<div class= "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-06"></div>
    <div class = "col-xs-06"></div>
    <div class = "col-xs-06"></div>
    <div class = "col-xs-06"></div>
</div>
```

Now on a button click I have to show Selection. How to do that?

Comment: You can do this by adding a class with `:after` and set position for that. Then addClass by JQery

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: @AjayMakwana and Kermani, I dont know how to do it?  Please help me

Comment: check [this] (http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/g3mu8/3/) try your  code over there

Comment: I must use Grid system @Don'tBenegative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is using css :after, and if you are using JQuery, that is easy to do it.

As I understand, what you need is this when one of the div[s] clicked, you show a mark (tick) at the top right corner of it. So,  [`2113`](https://css-tricks.com/put-checkmarks-next-to-visted-links-with-pure-css/) is the code for check mark(tick) and you can use it in CSS `content`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class= "row our-div">
    <div class = "col-xs-6">div1</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-6">div2</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-6">div3</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-6">div4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.active:after{
 font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\2713";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    color: white;
    background:green;
    border-radius:25px;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    text-align:center;
}

.our-div > div{
  height:100px;
  background:purple;
   color:white;
}
```

**JavaScript (JQuery):**

```
$(".our-div div").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[DEMO - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kksz64k6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can `addClass()` on click for each or add class to all .mark

```
$(".className").click(function(){
    $(".className").addClass("mark");
});
```

to mark and unmark use `toggleClass()`

**Reference:**

1. [jQuery toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
2. [jQuery addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)